# javax.json: Adding a value to a javax JsonValue

Tags: java, json, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to add a value to a list of JsonValue. Is it possible to do this?

A bit of background, I am retrieving a Json response from a Rest API, within this Json is a list of Names like this:

`{ 
   "Name" : {Name1, Name2, Name3, ...} 
}`

I need to add another name to list so I can modify names through the Rest API. You are able to perform this task as I have it working in PowerShell, however I can not use PowerShell in the final program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify JSONObject as it is immutable.
You might want to explore GSON API to update JSONObject.